# Abstract function and timers

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am pretty new to inheritance. Trying to implement a base class with a static timer. This timer will call an abstract function every time the time has elapsed. The reason is that two classes that inhereting from the base class will have a synchronized timers. Here is the code

Base class:

```
 public abstract class UIControllers
{
    public enum IndicatorColors
    {
        Green,
        Red,
        Yellow,
        Blue
    }

    private static Timer UITimer;

    public UIControllers()
    {
        EnableUITimer();
    }

    private int intervalInMillis = 500;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables the timer responsible for UI effect in the GUI. 
    /// </summary>
    private void EnableUITimer()
    {
        if (UITimer != null)
        {
            return;                
        }

        UITimer = new Timer();
        UITimer.Interval = intervalInMillis;
        UITimer.Elapsed += UITimer_Elapsed;
        UITimer.Start();
    }

    private void UITimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeElapsed();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The function is being called when the time interval ellapsed
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void TimeElapsed();
```

...

Derived class:

```
    protected override void TimeElapsed()
    {
     ....
    }
```

It only works for one of my two classes that inheriting from the base class (whichever class was instantiated first it works for it).

Thanks

Comment: We need to see your full implementation.  Provide us with enough code to reproduce and understand the problem.

Comment: I don't think we can debug `....` for you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EnableUITimer()`, you wave off if the static instance has been created, so the only subclass instance that ever gets to give `UITimer` an event handler is the one that creates it -- the first one, as you noticed. The event handler is an instance method, a delegate.

Instead, do this:

```
private void EnableUITimer()
{
    if (UITimer != null)
    {
        //  If it already exists, give it a handler from this instance. 
        //  Every instance that wants to be notified has to provide its own 
        //  event handler. 
        UITimer.Elapsed += UITimer_Elapsed;
        return;
    }

    UITimer = new Timer();
    UITimer.Interval = intervalInMillis;
    UITimer.Elapsed += UITimer_Elapsed;
    UITimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: But then they will not be synchronized. I create a static timer because i only need one that controls something in UI from different controllers

Comment: So I am bit confused now. I know that my Timer is static. the reason I i checked for null was cause i did not want to "destroy" the previous instance of timer which one of the class had a reference to. Where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: @M.Levin The flaw is that `UITimer_Elapsed` is a delegate. It comes with its own `this`. When the first subclass gives `UITimer` an event handler, that event handler is only called for the instance that provided it. Imagine if your form gives a Button a Click handler. You don't want EVERY Form to be notified when that Button is clicked -- only the form that gave it the handler. And that's how it works. Every *instance*  that wants to handle that event from that object has to explicitly provide its own handler.

Answer (score 0):

This section of code gets run 2x (once for each object instance)

```
    public UIControllers()
    {
        EnableUITimer();
    }
```

UITimer is static and null on first execution so ALL of EnableUITimers executes on the FIRST instance. With the second instance UITimer != null is true so EnableUITimer returns without creating the timer and wiring up UITImer_Elasped.

```
private void EnableUITimer()
{
    if (UITimer != null)
    {
        return; // Exits on second instance
    }
```

What you probably want to do is skip creating the timer if it is already instanced, but still wire up to the Elapsed event

```
private void EnableUITimer()
{
    if (UITimer == null)
    {
        UITimer = new Timer();
        UITimer.Interval = intervalInMillis;
        UITimer.Start();
    }
    UITimer.Elapsed += UITimer_Elapsed;        
}
```